# Can the field (underlying a vector space) always be considered a 1-dimensional vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, scalar-fields

For example.

- We know that a linear transformation is **exactly** the unique homomorphism between vector spaces, therefore applying a linear transformation to a vector always leads to a vector.
- At the same time, we know that the dual vector is the linear transformation that maps a vector to an element of the underlying field.

Combining the two, this means that the field element mapped from the dual vector is still a member of a vector space (which has to be one-dimensional, because it is a single element).

Can the field (underlying a vector space) always be considered as a uni-dimensional vector space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A field $\mathbb{K}$ can always be considered to be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space of dimension 1. It does not depend on the fact that there may pre-exist, or not, some other vector space for which $\mathbb{K}$ is the underlying field.

To prove this, it is enough to show one construction and there is one which is trivial: let $V = \mathbb{K}$ and let $ \cdot $ denote the internal product from $ \mathbb{K} \times \mathbb{K}$ to $\mathbb{K}$. Now define $*$, the external product from $ \mathbb{K} \times V $ to $V$, as being:
$$k * v := k \cdot v$$
(let the external product be the internal one, disguised).

Then it is easy to show that $(V,+,*)$ is a 1-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. No duals involved.

Comment: thank you. then, technically speaking, don't you feel like books should NOT say that a dual is a linear map from a vector space to its field? Since a map is said linear if and only if it is a homomorphism between vector spaces, then to be more precise books should define duals as the linear maps from a vector space to another vector space, given by the field (of the first vector space) over itself

Answer (score 0):

> Can the field (underlying a vector space) always be considered as a uni-dimensional vector space?

Not by itself, because a vector space is really two things that play nicely with each other: an abelian group (the vectors) and a field (the scalars).

Since a field is by definition an abelian group, it follows immediately that a field over itself is a vector space. The single basis element is trivially 1 (although that's not the only possibility).

Comment: let $b$ be an nonzero element of the field. Then $\{b\}$ is a basis of the field, viewed as a vector space over itself. $b$ needn't be $1$ (unless the field is $\{0, 1\}$).

Comment: @LoutchoGlotuk Thanks for that. I've updated my answer.